# Getting Ad Campaign impressions for stopped Ad

Tags: ads, huawei-mobile-services

My Huawei Ad campaign was stopped 21 april but in appsflyer installs and impressions still comes. What could be the reason?

Answer (score 0):

It is a normal scenario. Users can activate the app on any day. After the task is suspended, the system does not place new ads. It is probably due to the cache and large number of ads that have been put out before are still valid and that's why these figures come out.